# Create polyhedralsurfaceZ from vertex table with make_solid() PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, 3d, geometry, postgis, qgis

I'm trying to get a 3D polygon using [`ST_MakeSolid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeSolid.html)() sfcgal function in PostGIS.

My table looks like this:

```
 id_geom| xmin | xmax    |  ymin   |   ymax  | zmin  | zmax
--------+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-------
   1 | 12.3235 | 12.3239 | 45.4339 | 45.4341 |    -7 |   -14
   2 | 12.3234 | 12.3238 | 45.4338 | 45.4339 |    -2 |    -7
```

I want another column with the geometry of the solid, but I can't figure out how to use vertex coordinates stored into my table instead of raw coordinates.

I read the question ["ST_MakeSolid() creating an invalid solid from closed polyhedralsurfaceZ"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214572/st-makesolid-creating-an-invalid-solid-from-closed-polyhedralsurfacez), and works:

```
SELECT ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
((0 0 0,0 1 0,1 1 0,1 0 0,0 0 0)),
((0 0 1,1 0 1,1 1 1,0 1 1,0 0 1)),
((0 0 0,0 0 1,0 1 1,0 1 0,0 0 0)),
((0 1 0,0 1 1,1 1 1,1 1 0,0 1 0)),
((1 1 0,1 1 1,1 0 1,1 0 0,1 1 0)),
((1 0 0,1 0 1,0 0 1,0 0 0,1 0 0)))')
```

But I want use "xmin", "xmax", etc. instead of 12.3235, 12.3239 etc..

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you're not sure how to concat the columns with the geometry string? `SELECT ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (' || a_column || ' ' || b_column || ' ...') FROM mytable`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jim Jones i solved the issue:

```
SELECT
ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z ('
'('||'('||xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_||')'||')'||','||
'('||'('||xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_||')'||')'||','||
'('||'('||xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_||')'||')'||','||    
'('||'('||xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_||')'||')'||','||        
'('||'('||xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymax_ ||' '||zmin_||')'||')'||','|| 
'('||'('||xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmax_ ||','|| xmin_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_ ||','|| xmax_ ||' '|| ymin_ ||' '||zmin_||')'||')'||')'                        
)
FROM mytable
```